# Mule cloud hub does not display flow name in the Insight tab

Tags: mule, cloudhub

I have defined a Mule flow like the below and enabled event tracking within it

```
<flow name="DownloadFTPFileIntoLocalFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="InputSFTP" host="${source.host}" port="22" path="${source.path}" user="${source.username}" 
    password="${source.password}" responseTimeout="90000" pollingFrequency="${source.pollingfrequency}" sizeCheckWaitTime="1000" doc:name="InputSFTP" autoDelete="true">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="[Z].*\.csv" caseSensitive="false" />
    </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <flow-ref name="ProcessCSVFlow" doc:name="ProcessCSVFlow"/>
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="InputSFTP" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" host="${source.host}" port="22" 
            path="${source.processed.path}" user="${source.username}" password="${source.password}" responseTimeout="10000" duplicateHandling="addSeqNo" doc:name="MoveToProcessedFolder"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="Default_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
```

I would expect that when I enable Cloudhub insight I begin to see Flow names as and when messages pass through this flow, but what I see is the below, if you notice carefully it is actually picking up the ***doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy***, the last message processor from the flow :)

[image: Cloud hub Insight]

Any ideas why it be like this. I am using Mule version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<exception-strategy ref="Default_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
```

to

```
<exception-strategy ref="Default_Exception_Strategy"/>
```

We need to remove the doc name, this is a work around as it seems to be a issue in Mule implementation